# How to do an http get in cocoa on the iPhone

Tags: cocoa, http, get

can anyone paste some code on how to do a simple http get in cocoa?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go!

This one grabs an image from a webserver.

```
    NSURL *url = [ NSURL URLWithString: [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.somewebsite.com/demo.png"] ]; 
    image = [ [ UIImage alloc ] initWithData: [ NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url ] ];
```

or, this one grabs a web page...

```
    NSURL *url = [ NSURL URLWithString:[ NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@", query ] ];
    NSURLRequest *request = [ NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url ];
```

To do it asynchronously, you should check out [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE).

Comment: I do the second example populating the query variable with @"joe". 

I then do:

NSData *responseData = [request HTTPBody ];

and response data comes back with 0 bytes of info.

Am I doing something wrong?  I want to get the response and convert to string

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `NSURLConnection`. You use it to request a URL, synchronously or (preferably) asynchronously. The full documentation for the URL system is here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html

But what you really probably want is:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE

Apple provides some sample code that should get you started.